Moveit not using sim time despite setting param
I am trying to do the moveit tutorials but using Gazebo too, and here is the error I am getting:
rviz2-7] [INFO] [1716835186.985014691] [move_group_interface]: Plan and Execute request accepted
[move_group-6] [WARN] [1716835188.103321492] [moveit_ros.current_state_monitor]: No state update received within 100ms of system clock. Have been waiting for 1.000000s, timeout is 1.000000s
[move_group-6] [INFO] [1716835188.103354576] [moveit_ros.current_state_monitor]: Didn't receive robot state (joint angles) with recent timestamp within 1.000000 seconds. Requested time 15.672000, but latest received state has time 0.000000.
[move_group-6] Check clock synchronization if your are running ROS across multiple machines!
[move_group-6] [WARN] [1716835188.103365368] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Failed to fetch current robot state.
[move_group-6] [INFO] [1716835188.103460827] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Combined planning and execution request received for MoveGroup action. Forwarding to planning and execution pipeline.
[move_group-6] [INFO] [1716835188.104811513] [moveit_ros.plan_execution]: Planning attempt 1 of at most 1
[move_group-6] [INFO] [1716835188.104845305] [moveit_move_group_capabilities_base.move_group_capability]: Using planning pipeline 'ompl'
[move_group-6] [INFO] [1716835188.109524747] [moveit.ompl_planning.model_based_planning_context]: Planner configuration 'manipulator' will use planner 'geometric::RRTConnect'. Additional configuration parameters will be set when the planner is constructed.
[move_group-6] [WARN] [1716835188.159985920] [moveit_trajectory_processing.time_optimal_trajectory_generation]: Joint acceleration limits are not defined. Using the default 1 rad/s^2. You can define acceleration limits in the URDF or joint_limits.yaml.
[move_group-6] [INFO] [1716835188.168032034] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 1 controllers in list
[move_group-6] [INFO] [1716835188.168055201] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 1 controllers in list
[move_group-6] [INFO] [1716835188.168414956] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Validating trajectory with allowed_start_tolerance 0.01
[move_group-6] [WARN] [1716835189.188197944] [moveit_ros.current_state_monitor]: No state update received within 100ms of system clock. Have been waiting for 0.899000s, timeout is 1.000000s
[move_group-6] [INFO] [1716835189.292359836] [moveit_ros.current_state_monitor]: Didn't receive robot state (joint angles) with recent timestamp within 1.000000 seconds. Requested time 16.873000, but latest received state has time 0.000000.
[move_group-6] Check clock synchronization if your are running ROS across multiple machines!
[move_group-6] [WARN] [1716835189.292381253] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Failed to validate trajectory: couldn't receive full current joint state within 1s
[move_group-6] [INFO] [1716835189.292546672] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Solution found but controller failed during execution
[rviz2-7] [INFO] [1716835189.293165014] [move_group_interface]: Plan and Execute request aborted

I understand that I am supposed to set the use_sim_time param to True on all nodes and I believe I did it right, and here's my launch file:
import os
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration, PythonExpression
from launch.conditions import IfCondition, UnlessCondition
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch.actions import ExecuteProcess
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from moveit_configs_utils import MoveItConfigsBuilder


def generate_launch_description():

    
    declare_simulator_flag= DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'simulator_flag',
        default_value='True',
        description='Whether to start the simulator',
    )

    declare_headless_flag = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'headless',
        default_value='False',
        description='Headless means only server is started without GUI',
    )

    # Command-line arguments
    ros2_control_hardware_type = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        "ros2_control_hardware_type",
        default_value="mock_components",
        description="ROS2 control hardware interface type to use for the launch file -- possible values: [mock_components, isaac]",
    )

    use_simulator = LaunchConfiguration("simulator_flag")
    headless = LaunchConfiguration("headless")

    moveit_config = (
        MoveItConfigsBuilder("mycobot")
        .robot_description(
            file_path="config/gen3_robotiq_2f_140.urdf.xacro",
            mappings={
                "ros2_control_hardware_type": LaunchConfiguration(
                    "ros2_control_hardware_type"
                )
            },
        )
        .robot_description_semantic(file_path="config/gen3_robotiq_2f_140.srdf")
        .trajectory_execution(file_path="config/moveit_controllers.yaml")
        .planning_pipelines(
            pipelines=["ompl", "pilz_industrial_motion_planner"]
        )
        .to_moveit_configs()
    )

    # Start the actual move_group node/action server
    move_group_node = Node(
        package="moveit_ros_move_group",
        executable="move_group",
        output="screen",
        parameters=[moveit_config.to_dict(), {"use_sim_time": True}],
        arguments=["--ros-args", "--log-level", "info"],
    )

    # RViz
    rviz_base = os.path.join(
        get_package_share_directory("mycobot_moveit_config"), "config"
    )
    rviz_config = os.path.join(rviz_base, "moveit.rviz")
    rviz_node = Node(
        package="rviz2",
        executable="rviz2",
        name="rviz2",
        output="log",
        arguments=["-d", rviz_config],
        parameters=[
            moveit_config.robot_description,
            moveit_config.robot_description_semantic,
            moveit_config.planning_pipelines,
            moveit_config.robot_description_kinematics,
            {"use_sim_time": True},
        ],
    )

    # Static TF
    static_tf_node = Node(
        package="tf2_ros",
        executable="static_transform_publisher",
        name="static_transform_publisher",
        output="log",
        arguments=["0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "world", "base_link"],
    )

    # Publish TF
    robot_state_publisher = Node(
        package="robot_state_publisher",
        executable="robot_state_publisher",
        name="robot_state_publisher",
        output="both",
        parameters=[
            moveit_config.robot_description,
            {"use_sim_time": True},
        ],
    )

    start_gazebo_server_cmd = ExecuteProcess(
        condition=IfCondition(use_simulator),
        cmd=[
            'gzserver',
            '-s',
            'libgazebo_ros_init.so',
            '-s',
            'libgazebo_ros_factory.so',
            'myworld.world',
        ],
        # cwd=[launch_dir],
        output='screen',
    )

    start_gazebo_client_cmd = ExecuteProcess(
        condition=IfCondition(PythonExpression([use_simulator, ' and not ', headless])),
        cmd=['gzclient'],
        # cwd=[launch_dir],
        output='screen',
    )

    gazebo_spawner = Node(
        package='gazebo_ros',
        executable='spawn_entity.py',
        arguments=['-topic', 'robot_description', '-entity', 'my_robot'],
        output='screen',
        emulate_tty=True,
    )

    return LaunchDescription(
        [
            declare_simulator_flag,
            declare_headless_flag,
            ros2_control_hardware_type,
            start_gazebo_server_cmd,
            start_gazebo_client_cmd,
            robot_state_publisher,
            gazebo_spawner,
            static_tf_node,
            move_group_node,
            rviz_node,
        ]
    )
```


I have experienced a similar issue (Didn't receive robot state (joint angles) with recent timestamp within 1.000000 seconds or Unable to fetch the current robot state). Requested time 16.873000, but latest received state has time 0.000000. with the UR10e simulation running on Ignition Gazebo (ROS2 Humble distro). When you launch a node that will use in the future the move_group_interface class, you need to pass in the parameters of the launch file the flag use_sim_time set to True. In this way, I'm able to retrieve the getCurrentPose().pose from the moveit_interface (moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface group(node, "ur_manipulator).
First, run the simulation:
ros2 launch ur_simulation_gz ur_sim_moveit.launch.py ur_type:=ur10e
Second, run your own node where you want to retrieve the move group interface:
ros2 launch you_own_pkg you_launch_file.launch.py
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument

def generate_launch_description():
    use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration("use_sim_time")
    return LaunchDescription([
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
                "use_sim_time",
                default_value="true",
                description="Using or not time from simulation",
            ),
        Node(
            package='planning_utilities_pkg',
            executable='planning_server',
            output='screen',
            parameters=[{
                "use_sim_time": use_sim_time,
            },
        ]
        )
    ])

This is the example node implemented in C++:
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>
#include <memory>
// MoveitCpp
#include <moveit/moveit_cpp/moveit_cpp.h>
#include <moveit/moveit_cpp/planning_component.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/msg/point_stamped.h>
#include <moveit/move_group_interface/move_group_interface.h>

#include <moveit_visual_tools/moveit_visual_tools.h>

namespace rvt = rviz_visual_tools;

// All source files that use ROS logging should define a file-specific
// static const rclcpp::Logger named LOGGER, located at the top of the file
// and inside the namespace with the narrowest scope (if there is one)
static const rclcpp::Logger LOGGER = rclcpp::get_logger("moveit_cpp_tutorial");

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  rclcpp::NodeOptions node_options;
  RCLCPP_INFO(LOGGER, "Initialize node");

  // This enables loading undeclared parameters
  // best practice would be to declare parameters in the corresponding classes
  // and provide descriptions about expected use
  node_options.automatically_declare_parameters_from_overrides(true);
  rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr node = rclcpp::Node::make_shared("run_moveit_cpp", "", node_options);

  // We spin up a SingleThreadedExecutor for the current state monitor to get information
  // about the robot's state.
  rclcpp::executors::SingleThreadedExecutor executor;
  executor.add_node(node);
  std::thread([&executor]() { executor.spin(); }).detach();

  // BEGIN_TUTORIAL
  //
  // Setup
  // ^^^^^
  //
  static const std::string PLANNING_GROUP = "ur_manipulator";
  static const std::string LOGNAME = "moveit_cpp_tutorial";
  // ros2_controllers
  static const std::vector<std::string> CONTROLLERS(1, "panda_arm_controller");

  /* Otherwise robot with zeros joint_states */
  rclcpp::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

  RCLCPP_INFO(LOGGER, "Starting MoveIt Tutorials...");
  moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface group(node, PLANNING_GROUP);
  auto pose_msg = group.getCurrentPose().pose;
  RCLCPP_INFO(node->get_logger(), "Current Pose is: %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f",
   pose_msg.position.x,
   pose_msg.position.y,
   pose_msg.position.z,
   pose_msg.orientation.x,
   pose_msg.orientation.y,
   pose_msg.orientation.z,
   pose_msg.orientation.w);
  RCLCPP_INFO(LOGGER, "Shutting down.");
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}

